# Security of Saving user data on mobile

Tags: android, security, webservice-client

My mobile app has users, so after someone log in, I send back the user id to be used for future requests (GET and POST HTTP web service calls to manage user data), and I store it in an sqlite table called user_settings after encrypting it using jbcrypt along with the salt. is this a safe way to do it?

Comment: It is unclear what you really do. How could you make use of the hashed information in future calls? If you really use HTTP and not HTTPS than it's never secure.

Comment: no, it is not. If someone accesses the device, they can find the encryption key, as I assume it is somewhere in the app (unless it is only fetched from the server, but even then, the device can be compromised to accept any https certificate (read: not yours, as in a mitm attack)). Nothing that you store on the device is safe. It can be more or less safe, but never entirely.

Comment: What is the security threat?

Comment: thx .. so what's the best way to keep track of a user's session in android instead of user id? in the backend I'm using jersey to make java web services to handle user requests (i.e. login, request/post data, upload files, ... etc)?

Comment: @M.R.M at the least, you should make sure that your server uses HTTPS and you only allow your client to connect over HTTPS. A bit of extra security can be had by using certificate pinning, so that the client will only connect to a server with a pre-defined certificate (i.e. your server's certificate). If you want an extra level of paranoia, you can use client certificates. One last idea is to generate a one-time use token for the client to use to authenticate with the server for each session, instead of a persistent user id.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) to encrypt the database with a randomly-generated key, created on first startup, that you store in [the Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

As @njzk2 said, there is no way to absolutely protect this data. Encrypting the database with a random, unique key, and stashing that key in the keystore, will make things much more difficult for an attacker, even with physical access to the device. In this scenario, the goal is not to keep the attacker from ever accessing the password, but slowing the attacker down enough that the user can change their password before the attacker can use it.

Comment: thx FSQ .. could you please answer my question in the comments on the original question?